# Struct member selected from type, it is not visible and will not be selected

Tags: unix, ocaml

I have a function that uses the Unix lib for its time functions:

```
let rfc822 (t: Unix.tm) : string =
    Printf.sprintf "%s, %s %s %d %s:%s:%s %s"
    (List.nth short_days t.tm_wday)
    (padInt t.tm_yday 2 "0")
    (List.nth short_month t.tm_mon)
    (t.tm_year + 1900)
    (padInt t.tm_hour 2 "0")
    (padInt t.tm_min 2 "0")
    (padInt t.tm_sec 2 "0")
    "GMT"
```

I'm getting this warning:

```
ocamlbuild -libs unix,str -Is recore/src,ostd/src,owebl/src app.native
+ /usr/bin/ocamlc -c -I recore/src -I ostd/src -I owebl/src -o recore/src/time.cmo recore/src/time.ml
File "recore/src/time.ml", line 45, characters 27-34:
Warning 40: tm_wday was selected from type Unix.tm.
It is not visible in the current scope, and will not 
be selected if the type becomes unknown.
File "recore/src/time.ml", line 46, characters 14-21:
Warning 40: tm_yday was selected from type Unix.tm.
It is not visible in the current scope, and will not 
be selected if the type becomes unknown.
File "recore/src/time.ml", line 46, characters 4-28:
Error: This expression has type 'a -> string
   but an expression was expected of type string
Command exited with code 2.
Compilation unsuccessful after building 13 targets (12 cached) in 00:00:00.
Makefile:8: recipe for target 'old' failed
make: *** [old] Error 10
```

How do I deal with this warning? I would much rather avoid `open`ing the Unix module if possible.

(Please ignore the actual compile error.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write `t.Unix.tm_yday`

```
$ ocaml
        OCaml version 4.02.1

# let f (t: Unix.tm) = t.tm_yday;;
Warning 40: tm_yday was selected from type Unix.tm.
It is not visible in the current scope, and will not
be selected if the type becomes unknown.
val f : Unix.tm -> int = <fun>

# let f (t: Unix.tm) = t.Unix.tm_yday;;
val f : Unix.tm -> int = <fun>
```

**Update**

To find this in the documents, you need to look for the definition of [`field`](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/names.html#field):

```
field   ::= [ module-path . ]  field-name
```

A field name can include a module name (or a sequence of module names, for nested modules) before the field name itself.

**Update 2**

There are also two syntaxes for opening a module locally. They look like overkill for this tiny function, but might be tidier for more complex ones. The module's symbols are directly available throughout the subexpression.

```
$ ocaml
        OCaml version 4.02.1

# let f t = Unix.(t.tm_yday);;
val f : Unix.tm -> int = <fun>

# let f t = let open Unix in t.tm_yday;;
val f : Unix.tm -> int = <fun>
```

These are documented as language extensions in [Local opens](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/extn.html#sec225).

Comment: Awesome. Where is the documentation for that syntax?